# Serials of errors on memcache.get -> gae_override.httplib

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running Python on GAE with 5-10 requests/second for now.
For the last two day I can't stop getting the following error:

```
...    
result = memcache.get(url)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 559, in get
        results = rpc.get_result()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
        return self.__get_result_hook(self)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 624, in __get_hook
        self._do_unpickle)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 271, in _decode_value
        return do_unpickle(value)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 401, in _do_unpickle
        return unpickler.load()
    ImportError: No module named gae_override.httplib
```

The point is that I have some "serials" during the day. Most of the time it looks good, but then I can receive 50-100 errors one by one.

I haven't touched that code for a couple of weeks, so the problem have existed for the last two days. The Internet doesn't have so much info on that (nothing at all, actually).

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will note in the stack trace it is saying it can't import a module `gae_override`.
a module called `gae_override` is not part of the appengine runtime.

That code is trying to re-consitute an entity stored in memcache and to do that
will need to import some of your code for model/entity definition, and it can't find the `gae_override` module.

My guess is you are doing some path manipulation in your code somewhere for custom libraries however it's not done in a consistent place. In this case the paths aren't correct and the import fails.  Do you use `appengine_config.py` to setup your paths for import ?  What sort of request is getting the error - for instance is it a newly started and this is the first request it processess ?

Comment: I don't use `appengine_config.py` at all. Main thing, that I didn't change anything since two weeks update.

Comment: You should be using appengine_config.py to set up paths. Have you looked at what sort of requests are getting the error.   The fact is gae_override is not part of the SDK and is your code, so maybe you are getting new requests going through a part of code you haven't tested on instance startup handling this type of request.

Comment: At least look at this, and prove otherwise then you might be able to build a test case, so you can log a bug.  But my guess is it's in your code.

Comment: Actually, this kind of failures appear periodically and don't depend on when an instance was created. 
Anyway I will try your suggestions and report back in a few hours :)

Comment: ALso check if you had any DeadlineExceededError on instance startup.  In the old days (first year or two of appengine) you could get a situation where a DEE on instance startup (during import) could lead to failed imports on subsequent requests. With warmup requests this has gone away.

Comment: At least I now resolved the error, but still can't figure out the actual cause of it. The point is that I cached the result-object of urlfetch. Actually - there was no need in that. So I've just started to cache result.content instead of original object. Content is `str` basically, so there are no problems with unpickling.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the help! The most interesting thing for me that instance remains the same actually. Problem appears periodically on normally running instance which successfully served several former requests with exact code. So from time to time it can't find `gae_override` internal module...

Comment: As you discovered it makes no sense to cache a result object.  The content, plus some headers in a dict would be all I would cache.